# divide two values derived from html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the average of two user defined numbers. However when you input a decimal the division function does not work, as if it get ignored.

Here is my javascript:

```
var boxamnt = "tempvalue for amount of boxes will change this later as needed";
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('value1').value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('value2').value);
  var abc = x + y;
  var total = abc/"2.00000000000000";
  alert(total);
```

Here is my form:

```
 First value: <input type="number" name="FirstValue" placeholder="Number" id="value1" step=".00000000000000"><br>
  Second value: <input type="number" name="NextValue" placeholder="Number" id="value2" step=".00000000000000"><br>
```

Comment: What is your specific reason for dividing by a STRING?

Comment: First, fix your question with the form html. Second what is the decimal separator for the inputted numbers? Do you check it's dot and not comma?

Comment: hmm, has anyone mentioned that you're dividing by a string yet... oh wait, nvm js is loosly typed so it gets converted to a number..

Comment: doesn't matter that it's a string: https://jsfiddle.net/qg9gvh80/